# Spring can't autowire webservice bean defined in context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cxf

I have spring context, very simple

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="by.test.**"/>
<bean id="clientService" class="by.test.WebServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

This bean is implementation of cxf web service

```
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebServiceInterface{
    //overriden methods
}
```

`WebServiceInterface` is generated from wsdl interface for webservice. When I trying to use something like

```
@Autowired
WebServiceInterface clientService;
```

It errors with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. When I autowire application context and get my bean from it, it's ok and I can get my bean with the help of 
`appContext.getBean("clientService")`
Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: post full error, config and  the src code

Comment: Sorry, but I have no opportunity to do this @localhost999

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
WebServiceInterface clientService;
```

Must reside in a class which is placed under a package covered by

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.test"/>
```

Comment: I use `@Autowired` in controller class, marked as `@Controller` and it under a package

Comment: Use by.test instead of by.test.**

Answer (score 0):

You must add this config in your ApplicationContext.xml :

`<context:annotation-config/>`

Answer (score 0):

Add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your **spring context file** adding `schemaLocation` based on your version of Spring (for me it's 4.x) and also change **base package to "by.test"**, as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="by.test"/>
  <bean id="clientService" class="by.test.WebServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```